# Javascript to insert css class when the user open a specific Url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

when the user open the page: contact.html

I would like insert the class: `.contact` in `.sidebar` class

when the user open the page: products.html

I would like insert the class: `.products` in `.sidebar` class

html:

```
<div class="sidebar">


</div>
```

js:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
     var loc = window.location.href; // returns the full URL
     if(/contact/.html(loc)) {
     $('.sidebar').addClass('contact');
     }
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't mix jquery and angularjs. But the best way to do this with Angular js is using ng-class

Comment: @Juanín Absolutely correct, but question doesn't seems to have angular code, so I remove angularjs tag from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.test(loc)` in your regex instead of `.html(loc)`. Like:

```
$(function() {
  var loc = window.location.href; // returns the full URL
  if(/contact/.test(loc)) {
    $('.sidebar').addClass('contact');
  }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i did not understand why .test where this come from, any explanation or link to explain me that function? thanks

Comment: @noob-fella You are using a regular expression `/contact/` and therefore can call regex functions on it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `/contact/.test(loc)`. `.html` is not a function that you can call on a regular expression.